# Can I switch between Move, Rotate & Scale and confirm previous transformation at the same time?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, transforms, shortcut

I'm using shortcuts `g`, `r`, `s`, but Blender cancel my previous transformation when I switch between them. What if I need to save current **move** position and **rotate** at that new location, and then **scale** at a new rotation?

Is it possible without `LMB` confirm mouse click? Looks like a pretty intuitive feature but I can find it.

Comment: either hit return or click with the mouse before tapping next g,r,s

Comment: Thanks for comment! I'm starting to get used to mouse click. Seems I don't like the sound of my mouse and unconsciously avoid clicks :D